# Same query on phpmyadmin and vb.net get different results

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin

I'm getting different query results from using phpmyadmin directly and on vb.net.

I used this query `SELECT * FROM tbllocation WHERE loc_name LIKE '%ROOM%'`

Here's the phpmyadmin and database server version:

[image: Here's the phpmyadmin and database server version.]

Here are the results from phpmyadmin:

[image: Here are the results from phpmyadmin]

Results from vb.net:

[image: Results from vb.net]

Here's my code in vb.net for getting and showing the query results.

```
 cmd.CommandText = q
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim rowindex As Integer = 0
    If dr.Read Then
        While dr.Read
            MsgBox(dr(1))
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr(1), dr(2), "", "")
            DataGridView1.Rows(rowindex).Tag = dr(0)
            rowindex += 1
        End While
    End If
    dr.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `Read` you advance to the next record. You are calling `Read` twice before using any data, so you're discarding the first record. If you want an `If` statement at all then test `HasRows`, not `Read`. That said, the `If` statement is pointless if you don't have an `Else` to do something specific if there are no records. As it is, your `While` loop does everything you need.

EDIT: In fact, I would recommend getting rid of the loop too.  Create a `DataTable` and call its `Load` method to load the contents of the data reader into it, then bind the `DataTable` to the grid.

EDIT: Taking things a step further, it appears that you are editing the data, in which case I would recommend not using a data reader at all.  Use a data adapter to populate a `DataTable`, bind that to the grid (preferably via a `BindingSource`), make changes to the `DataTable` and then use the same data adapter to save the changes. Whatever you're currently doing to save changes is just complicating things.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to fix my code. Thank you for giving me more detailed explanation about `read` function.

Comment: Can i customize the data to be shown on the datagridview if I will be using the data table? Because when I use data table it shows everything inside it.

Comment: You can add the columns to the grid that you want in the designer (which you are presumably already doing) and set the `DataPropertyName` of each to tell it how to bind. Before you set the `DataSource` in code, you set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` and no extra columns will be added.

Comment: That said, why are you retrieving that you don't need in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for giving me further knowledge.